# O(G)=36 and o(H) =4 then H = Z(G)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order 36 and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order 4. Then which of the following are true?

a) $H$ is a proper subgroup of $Z(G)$ (center of $G$)

b) $H = Z(G)$

c) $H$ is normal in $G$

d) $H$ is abelian

Solution:

$o(H) = 4$ therefore $H$ is abelian. $H$ is a $2$-sylow subgroup $n_2={1,3,9}$ therefore $H$ need not be normal always. Since $H$ is abelian It will be a subgroup of $Z(G)$. How to prove it is equal to $Z(G)$ or a proper subgroup of $Z(G)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $H$ is not necessarily to be a subgroup of $Z(G)$.

$G = D_{36} = \langle r\rangle:\langle s\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_{18}:\mathbb{Z}_2$, a semi-direct product. Now $Z(G) = \{1,r^9\}$.

Comment: An element in an abelian subgroup is not necessarily to be commutative with all the elements in the big group $G$.

Comment: I think that is what the author of this answer intended, @Hongyi

Comment: So it is a counterexample: $Z(G)$ is of order $2$ but $H$ is of order $4$, which cannot be a subgroup of a group of order $2$.

Comment: Correct. I think that is what the author of this answer intended. Although, this still doesn't state which condition is necessarily true (or provide a counterexample to each statement).

Comment: Thank you Hongyi...yeah now i got it...that H need not ba subgroup of Z(G) but can you bit explain further in $D_{36}$. I dont know about semi direct groups pls.

Comment: $D_{36} = \langle r,s:r^{18} = s^2 = 1 = (rs)^2\rangle$, the dihedral group of order $36$.

Comment: Do you know some conditions that the statement is true? I have no idea. (Other than $G$ to be nilpotent.)@Clayton